# Completely disable android keyboard on phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I am writing Phonegap application, and i need to support Android 2.3 - 4.1.
On earlier android there are some bugs with keyboard, so I've created custom one on html. Now, I need for all androids version API <= 10 turn of virtual keyboard. Any ideas how to completely programmatically disable it?

Thanks,
-Dima

Answer (score 0):

put below code in your manifest file, inside actvity node

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

it may help you

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

> On earlier android there are some bugs with keyboard

First, there are many implementations of "virtual keyboards" in use in Android.

Second, I am not aware that Web developers have generally had problems with Android's soft keyboards. You are welcome to provide links to evidence supporting your claim.

> Now, I need for all androids version API <= 10 turn of virtual keyboard. Any ideas how to completely programmatically disable it?

That is not possible. However, if your Web page does not have anything that allows conventional text input (e.g., `<textarea>`), then the soft keyboard typically will not appear on its own.

Comment: Well, i got a lot of inputs there. So, if page is long enough, after soft keyboard pop ups there some issues with the scroll. My idea - is to create custom keyboard - which will be invisible, and use it in case API is less then 10.

Comment: @dimko1: Wouldn't it be better, and simpler, to come up with a UI design that avoids "a lot of inputs there"?

Comment: @dimko1: That does not mean that on one Web page you need "a lot of inputs".

Comment: Actually that is not to much input text boxes, only 4 or 5. But design is approved by customer, so we need to find solution:)